# Detect first launch of a browser in JavaScript to perform some action

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, session-cookies

I would like to know if it exists a way to detect the first launch of a browser instance in Javascript ?

In this case i would like to delete one of my session cookie.

Here is the problem :

In fact, i have build an application where the user can access only one time to my application in the same browser (tab or window). When the user is connected to my app, a session cookie is created. This cookie is deleted when the user close the browser or the tab. After that, if the user try to open 2 times my application in 2 differents tab for example, i am able to check if an instance of my app already running, and if it is the case i show a message to the user : "You are not granted to access 2 times the app in the same browser". When the user close the web page, i am able to delete the cookie. The problem is when the browser has crashed : My cookie stays and when the user restart the browser i prompt the message whereas there is no instance of my app already connected.

Regards

Comment: You can store the info about first run in Cookies or Local Storage.

Comment: If it is the first launch, how does the session cookie get created?

Comment: Do you mean literately after installation the first launch?

Comment: Instead of deleting the cookie, you could just set his expiration to 0 so it gets deleted by itself whenever the browser closes.

Comment: I have updated my post to better explain the problem. Could you have a look please ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of cookies, session cookies and normal cookies.

You can create a normal cookie with expiration in hundret years. If the cookie is present, its not the first visit.

Comment: If there's no expiration, then the cookie get destroyed when the browser closes.

Comment: The presence of the cookie might suggest it's not this first activation, but its absence certainly doesn't mean it's the first.

Comment: I have updated my post to better explain the problem. Could you have a look please ?